# When can a group be decomposed into a direct product of smaller groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any general condition that a group must satisfy in order to be decomposable into a direct sum or product of smaller groups? And what happens if one replaces 'direct product' with semi-direct product?

Comment: The statement that a group decomposes into a direct product of two (normal) subgroups is pretty straightforward and covered in a basic abstract algebra course.  Is that the sort of response you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard necessary and sufficient condition for $G$ to be a direct product is that $G$ has two proper normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ with $H \cap K = \{1\}$ and $HK=G$. For semidirect product, drop the requirement for $K$ to be normal.

If that is not the sort of answer that you are looking for, then you should make it clearer what sort of conditions you have in mind.

Comment: Is there a proof for this claim?

Comment: Yes of course, it's a standard result.